# Internal Server Error in Dedicated Server

Tags: php, .htaccess, facebook-graph-api

I'm having "500 Internal Server Error" in only one file which is accessing FB Graph API to get number of FB page details. I searched a lot about solution of the issue and what I got the three main things to check is

> **1) .htaccess file:** Which is correct
>
> **2) Permission Of the file:** Tried with even 777
>
> **3) Max Execution Time:** Tried with 100 seconds and still getting same
>   error.

Issue is not with the code as when I tried with increasing max exec time to 30 seconds, it gave me correct results with same error at end of the page but when I set it to 100 seconds again it throws me the same error.

I'm clue less and couldn't understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: Normally 500 Internal Server error comes because of .htaccess file error. Recheck it properly by commenting whole file and then uncomment each line one by one

Comment: You need to look at your server's error logs

Comment: Maybe posting some piece of code would help

Comment: JonLin - Thanks for your reply. I checked Error Logs but couldn't find anything there.

amarjitsngh - Thanks for your reply. I checked that but let me take a look again.

Leonardo - Thanks, I don't think there will be any bug in code as when I tried with 30 sec of exec time it worked. Though I'll paste the piece.